# Is anyone familiar with "VELCRO" as a term for a debugging level?

Tags: debugging, logging, error-logging, aol

In an older software package, I noticed an interesting "logging level" in the options for debug message output.  The list included DEBUG, WARNING, ERROR, FATAL, VELCRO, TRACE and STREAM. (Listed in that order.)

Might anyone have any idea what a "velcro" debuging message might be? It does not apperar to be a term related to the API or any other part of the application's framework.  I assume it to be an older 1990s-era debugging term.

Is anyone familiar with this term?

Comment: more likely it was a single-shop or even a single-programmer thing. I wouldn't read anything too deep into it :^)

Comment: perhaps it was a temporary debugging message meant to be ripped out later; not sewn in, but velcro'd on.